# Entity Framework - Insertion to a relational table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and i have to start a application within no time before learning EF in detail. 
I need a help in insertion to a relational table.
Suppose in my application I have two tables Staff and Departments and I have relation table 'StaffDepartment' which has FK constraints StaffID and DeptID. When I generate Models from database , StaffDepartment entity hasnt appeared in the EF. So how can i insert values to StaffDeparment table in EF as i have no dint get any object named 'StaffDepartment'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Boney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See walk-through below on generating the model:

[EF 4.1 Model & Database First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

i would also recommend the follwing guide from microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb399182.aspx

it shows in a quite simple way how to create/implement and work with a DB in the Entity Framework.

in my eyes you can start with the chapter: "Generating the School .edmx File". but of course it is good to read everything.

Berry

Answer (score 0):

Iam sorry for misunderstanding your question! after reading your question again i recongnised that you are looking for something else. But good news! i have exactly what you are looking for:

at first read this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/21/many-to-many-mappings-in-entity-framework.aspx

This article explains how to work with "Many to Many" relations.

This article was also very helpful:
http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/

it is a little bit easier to undestand because it describes also a way without lambda expressions.

Berry